# Can lombok.ToString include a field from a supertype without using callSuper?

Tags: java, lombok

I have an AbstractJPA entity and I'm using Lombok to generate the toString() method for all the subclasses.  I would like the field `id`, wich is on the super class, to be included, but I would like to do it such that it appears that the `id` field is part of the subclass.  So for example instead of getting this:

```
AggregatedSalesOrder(super=AbstractOCIDEntity(super=Entity of type com.example.domain.models.AggregatedSalesOrder with id: null), bucketIndex=null, quantity=null)
```

I would get:

```
AggregatedSalesOrder(id: null, bucketIndex=null, quantity=null)
```

Thoughts?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: I doubt that this would be supported, firstly because most Lombok features require no information outside of the current class (though there are some newer features, such as `@Delegate`, that have moved beyond that), and secondly because it would require the relevant superclass field to be non-private, which is a bad practice; I can't imagine Lombok having any features that depend on doing that.

Comment: Seems like it should be pretty straight forward to do something like includeSuper={id}.  Just make it a requirement that {id} has a public getter, and lombok can just build in a generated getId for that property.

Answer (score 2):

I know this comes a hundred years later and you probably don't even work with Java anymore, but now you can decorate classes with `@ToString(callSuper = true)` and it will output also the fields from the super class.
Hope it's useful for someone.

Comment: yea, but is there a way to include a field(s) from a supertype without having the word "Super" printed in the log (aka having @ToString(callSuper = true))

Comment: I think the question asks if we can remove the word "Super" from the toString output using the lombok annotation.

Comment: This answer leads to the original problem. Anyway seems it's not possible. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57253856/1386911