# How to get super fields in Lombok annotation handler

Tags: java, lombok

I want to modify the format of Lombok @ToString to make it behave like the toString code generated by IDEA. There is no option available so I try to modify Lombok source code lombok.javac.handlers.HandleToString.java. I want to get fields of parents till Object then join them with ", " but I can't find way to achieve it.

Now I can only reluctantly achieve it by recursion and String.substring method, but it is not very general. One of the decompilation results with my modified Lombok is as follows:

```
public String toString() {
        String varSuperToString = super.toString();
        int varStart = varSuperToString.indexOf("{") + 1;
        int varEnd = varSuperToString.lastIndexOf("}");
        String varSuperSub = "";

        try {
            varSuperSub = varSuperToString.substring(varStart, varEnd);
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException var6) {
        }

        if (!varSuperSub.isEmpty()) {
            varSuperSub = varSuperSub + ", ";
        }

        return "NonEmptyChild_NonEmptyParent{" + varSuperSub + "email=" + this.email + ", " + "city=" + this.city + "}";
    }
```

Lombok's toString: 
NonEmptyChild_NonEmptyParent(super=NonEmptyParent(id=8, name=zfff), email=zfff@qq.com, city=bj)

But I want:
NonEmptyChild_NonEmptyParent{id=8, name=zfff, email=zfff@qq.com, city=bj}

I think I need to get fields of parents till Object in Lombok annotation processor, but I don't how to get them. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 52):

Specify `callSuper=true` for calling super class `toString`

```
 @ToString(callSuper=true)
```

Using lombook annotation you cannot change the pattern, if you need any pattern changes you have to override the `toString`, Since super class fields are non private you can access them directly using `this` keyword

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TestModel {id=" + this.id +"name= "+this.name+"email= "+this.email+"city= "+this.city+ "}";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but callSuper means recursion. the result of  @ToString(callSuper=true, includeFieldNames=true) is NonEmptyChild_NonEmptyParent(super=NonEmptyParent(id=8, name=zfff), email=zfff@qq.com, city=bj), but I want NonEmptyChild_NonEmptyParent{id=8, name=zfff, email=zfff@qq.com, city=bj}

Comment: your concern is that printing `super` and super class name? @jnmj

Comment: Yes, and also replace '(' with '{'

Comment: are fields in super class or private ? @jnmj

Comment: all fields in current class and non-private fields in parents, like IDEA hot key: control + enter to generate toString() method

Comment: No other options you have to override,  updated the answer @jnmj

Answer (score 4):

Annotation processors like Lombok only have access to the compilation unit (i.e. Java file) that they are currently processing. They cannot access any superclass of the processed unit. That means that all generated code must solely rely on local information, and thus the superclass's fields can only be printed by the superclass's `toString()`.

The only way is to make Lombok generate some ugly string replacement code that removes the classname and the parentheses from the result of the `super.toString()` call. But you really should not do that. (Remember that you also have to change it for the Eclipse generator and in the IntelliJ plugin.)

NB: If something else relies on your `toString()` implementation, you should implement it manually to make that clear. If not, it's better to live with an imperfect format than to hack Lombok.

Comment: If access to the superclass is not available, then how does the compilation not choke when a local method calls a field or method on the superclass?

Comment: It's not available for annotation processors which run during an early stage of compilation. The resolution of such information takes place during the semantic analysis, which happens after annotation processing.

Comment: I just found this page. This info should be surfaced easier.  I have a much better understanding of Lombok and it's limitations now.

https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/wiki/LOMBOK-CONCEPT:-Resolution

Answer (score 1):

If you need a specific toString method you don't need to use Lombok at all. Just generate method with Intellij, modify it to your needs and it will be used from your java program. Lombok can make methods, but will respect your methods if you put your implementations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I hope to minimize handwritten codes by annotation. I worry that if I manually generate code, I need to modify get, set, toString and other methods when I add some new fields. Ideally, there are only fields and @Data annotations in a class. I wish I could do that.

Comment: @jnmj If you use IntelliJ generated `toString` code, I think that when you'll rename, add or delete a field, IntelliJ will propose you to automatically refactor `toString`, `equals` etc.

Comment: If you don't want to write and you don't want to generate each time toString(), then you can serialize your object to JSON and use it as a toString() metod. But this is risky, you can gen in infinite loop if you return some collection from parent or vice versa. The best option is to freeze the code at the time you are writing it. When you add new fields, then you need to take care, not now.